# Multiple break point analysis strucchange, significance of each breakpoint

Tags: r, time-series, breakpoints, p-value

I'm performing a time series analysis with multiple breakpoints in R.

I managed to identify three breakpoints using the procedure suggested in `strucchange` package but I'm struggling to get the significance (p-value) for these break points.

Here there is a dummy dataset and the code I was working with.
the dataset:

```
x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,
    29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,
    54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,
    79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94)
z=c(128,103,29,117,53,49,84,67,76,111,81,38,36,-35,-12,21,121,38,84,173,153,99,
    91,110,69,50,15,-50,15,-97,-2,13,107,47,137,25,-19,54,4,87,72,58,32,-4,75,50,
    80,65,124,56,58,-3,30,42,55,212,245,18,106,128,88,216,205,234,120,171,195,230,
    237,143,225,253,202,218,283,227,291,192,179,197,337,259,261,215,290,293,255,
    316,355,312,337,341,388,338)
df=data.frame(z,x)
plot(x,z)
```

the code:

```
# https://www.marinedatascience.co/blog/2019/09/28/comparison-of-change-point-detection-methods/
library(strucchange)
library(sandwich)
library(fxregime)

# get best model
opt_bpts <- function(x) {
  #x = bpts_sum$RSS["BIC",]
  n <- length(x)
  lowest <- vector("logical", length = n-1)
  lowest[1] <- FALSE
  for (i in 2:n) {
    lowest[i] <- x[i] < x[i-1] & x[i] < x[i+1]
  }
  out <- as.integer(names(x)[lowest])
  return(out)
}

#################################################################
#marinedatascience.co/blog/2019/09/28/comparison-of-change-point-detection-methods/
#Zeileis, A., Leisch, F., Hornik, K. & Kleiber, C. (2002), strucchange: An R Package for Testing for Structural Change in Linear Regression Models. J Stat Softw 7(2), 38p., doi: 10.18637/jss.v007.i02↩

z_ts <- as.ts(df$z) #crate time series

bpts <- breakpoints(z ~ x, data = df)
plot(bpts)

bpts_sum <- summary(bpts)
opt_brks <- opt_bpts(bpts_sum$RSS["BIC",])
opt_brks
# Nested syntax with 3 breaks:
ci=confint(bpts,breaks = 3)#, level = 0.99)
bpts <- breakpoints(breakpoints(z ~ x, data = df), breaks = 3)
Fst=Fstats(z_ts~1)

#here I get a p-value for the analysis with three breakpoints
plot(Fst)
sctest(Fst)
```

I get as `Fst` output:

```
    supF test

data:  Fst
sup.F = 203.23, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I would like to obtain (if it's possible) the p-value of each breakpoint.
Something like this:

```
F test
data:  Fst
breakpoint1:p-value < brk1.pvalue
breakpoint2:p-value < brk2.pvalue
breakpoint3:p-value < brk3.pvalue
```